# Glyph of Warding with touch effects

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, traps

I was DMing a game and eventually set up a scenario where the players had to choose between leaving their wagon, or bringing it to a dangerous place where it could be destroyed.

The enchanter thought it'd be a great idea to use two [Glyph of warding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glyph-of-warding) spells, one for [Touch of Idiocy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-idiocy) and one for [Suggestion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suggestion), to lower the will of whoever enters, then suggesting them to leave (which he worded reasonably enough).

Now the problem is the fact Touch of Idiocy is a touch spell with no other save. I'm not sure if the fact a person stands in the area counts as touching, or if the enchanter has to roll for a melee touch attack on a flat footed creature (which is just 10 most of the time)

There are a few other problems (how does suggesting a course of action work for the suggestion spell, decided on cast or in person? Can the enchanter stack the idiocy penalty with more glyphs as it has no label (circumstance, inherent, etc)?) but I can see it being justified as it doesn't affect mindless creatures and it only helps against one person, leaving the wagon vulnerable to future thieves (or even the same thief who later on gets brave again).

Comment: Ask your follow up questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Multiple [*glyphs of warding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glyph-of-warding) can't ward the same thing...

The target of the *glyph of warding* is listed as *object touched or up to 5 sq. ft./level*, and the spell's description says

> Multiple *glyphs* cannot be cast on the same area. However, if a cabinet has three different drawers, each can be separately warded.

This prevents chained *glyphs* exactly as you describe, and for good reason. For example, were multiple *glyphs* able to ward a lone tiny box, triggering them all simultaneously creates disastrous consequences for the approaching army—seriously, a tiny box *will* be picked by someone and opened (especially if it's a *shiny* box), and if there are hundreds of *glyphs of warding* on that tiny box then *boom*—goodbye, army. (To actually run such a trick, try the spell [*explosive runes*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/explosive-runes) instead.)

### ...And a touch spell stored in a [*glyph of warding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glyph-of-warding) will affect the creature that triggers the *glyph*

The spell's description says

> You can store any harmful spell of 3rd level or lower that you know. All level-dependent features of the spell are based on your caster level at the time of casting the glyph. **If the spell has a target, it targets the intruder.**

Emphasis mine. The spell [*touch of idiocy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-idiocy) has as its target *living creature touched*, so a living creature triggering a *glyph* storing *touch of idiocy* will be the target of the spell despite the spell's typical casting method. (By the way, multiple penalties from multiple *touches of idiocy*—as they're from the same source—*shouldn't* stack, but ask the DM; a [penalty](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Penalty) is a little more complicated than a [bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus), despite the lengths of those linked entries.)

Although the text isn't specific, it's safe to assume that summoned creatures from a spell *glyph* aren't *random* creatures from the *summon monster* list and instead chosen by the *glyph*'s creator when the *glyph* is created. Likewise, a *suggestion* spell held in *glyph* should offer a suggestion that the caster chooses upon creating the *glyph* rather than offering a suggestion of the caster's choosing when the *glyph* is activated.

#### That said, this is a really expensive way to secure a wagon

A [heavy wagon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/vehicles/land-vehicles/wagon-heavy) only costs 100 gp. Spending hundreds of gp to protect it is an unusual use of resources. If available, consider hiring some locals to guard it. They'll be *thankful* for the generous 1 gp per day that you pay them to *guard* your wagon.

Comment: +1, but you can chain Glyphs pretty easy.  You just have to be careful about it.  A wagon, as a really big object, is pretty easy to get multiple glyphs on (one on the door, one on each wheel, one on the whole wagon's interior, one on the floor, etc)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Chaining *glyphs* will depend a lot the generosity of the GM, though. I mean, sure, you could build a miniature chest of draws with 100 itty-bitty drawers and *glyph* each drawer and toss *that* at the army, but I'd expect the GM to toss a book right back at your head.

Comment: @HeyICanChan How you'd get every single person in the army to touch every single drawer is the question, if I'm imagining your scenario right, a person in the army has to pick it up, open it, and scrape his finger against all the tiny 1 mm wide drawers as they explode.

Comment: Everyone was too lazy to search for a nearby civilization and they had 400gp worth of diamond dust lying around for some reason... It was used to guard 16000 ish gold

Comment: @Teco I assume *summon monster III* because it's more interesting than a lot of things a *glyph* can do. In this case, it's *summon monster III* dumbed down to (1d4+1)×100 *summon monster I* creatures from a tiny chest of drawers picked up, unsuspectingly, drawer-side down, causing all the itty bitty drawers to open at once.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ooooh I see where you're coming from, but it depends on the interpretation of "any creature entering the warded area or opening the warded object". I'd rule that opening a drawer upside down is "physical probing", "Glyphs cannot be affected or bypassed by such means as physical or magical probing"

Comment: @Teco That'd be an interesting way to bypass a *glyph* then — by upending the whole desk! "You mean the *glyph* does *not* trigger, right, DM?" says the player. "Because when Tordek flipped over the desk, Tordek didn't open drawer; *gravity* opened the drawer!" Seriously, though, **a lot** of inventive uses for — and means to bypass — *glyphs* really are GM's calls.

Answer (score 2):

From *Glyph of Warding*

> If the spell has a target, it targets the intruder.

and

> Saving throws and spell resistance operate as normal.

So, *Touch of Idiocy* just works.  There is no attack roll, saving throw, or other failure chance involved, other than the chance that a clever intruder might bypass or not trigger the trap in the first place.

(Also: note that the enchanter cannot place two glyphs 'on the wagon'  as such; each glyph must ward a different, though not necessarily separate, area.  For example, he could ward the doorway and the main body of the wagon)

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, I think its just stepping in to the designated area.

If I read the spell description:

> Target or Area object touched or up to 5 sq. ft./level

So it would be the moment a character walks in the area they get a flatfooted touch attack but keep in mind though that Rogues and Barbarians are bit less easily caught flatfooted. What the too hit would be like the default 10 (maybe make sure it’s not too OP by checking the [Trap section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps) because it behaves as a trap).